# Performance issues on large CSV import with before INSERT trigger

Tags: mysql, performance, trigger, import

I am doing import csv file using load into file. The files are big and contains minimum 500K+ lines of records and table extend day by day. Each line is just a phone number and nothing else. My table size has now grown for records more than 200+ Mil. I am also using a trigger to update a few items before INSERT. A bulk import takes a very long time naturally because of the trigger.

To import records query

```
load data local infile '/tmp/file.csv' IGNORE into table contacts FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (contact) set phonebook_id = 1
```

Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER `contacts_before_insert`
BEFORE INSERT ON `contacts`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

   DECLARE vTimezone varchar(4);

   SELECT IF((timezone = '' OR count(timezone) = 0), 'ERR', timezone)
     INTO vTimeZone
     FROM timezones
    WHERE area_code = (SELECT LEFT(NEW.contact , 3));

   SET NEW.timezone = vTimezone;
```

timezone table structure

```
  CREATE TABLE `timezones` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `state` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `area_code` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    `timezone` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=327 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Contacts table structure

```
 CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `phonebook_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `campaign_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `contact` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   `status` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `admin` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `call_status` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `active_call` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `test_call` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `v_node_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
   `timezone` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   `updated_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `created_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `contact_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `phonebook_id` (`phonebook_id`,`contact`),
     KEY `idx_001` (`active_call`,`campaign_id`,`test_call`),
     KEY `idx_002` (`phonebook_id`,`call_status`,`test_call`,`campaign_id`,`active_call`,`dnc_contact`),
     KEY `idx_003` (`phonebook_id`,`test_call`,`call_status`,`dnc_contact`),
     KEY `FK_campaign_id_idx` (`campaign_id`),
     KEY `idx_testcall` (`test_call`),
     KEY `idx_004` (`campaign_id`,`call_status`,`test_call`),
     KEY `idx_active_call` (`active_call`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=136600117 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

My question is: if I break the CSV file into smaller pieces, say 2 Meg each or something like that, is that going to speed up the INSERT? Or, should I create some sort of stored procedure which runs after the import and updates the data in contacts table where my contacts are being imported. Not to mention, I absolutely want to avoid row/table locking because at the same time the table has heavy SELECT/UPDATES.

What would be the best practice here? How to speed up large CSV imports avoiding table locking etc .. ?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE timezones` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE contacts`

Comment: @Rick James timezones and contacts tables structures updated in question

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions are roughly in order of the performance benefit they will provide.

(1) (Similar to what a_vlad says) Rethink the use of a Trigger.  I would load the csv into a temp table, then do the timezone lookup in a single query.  Only then copy the data into the main table.  Other tips on [*High speed ingestion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) .  Tips on [*chunking*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) .  Yes, 500K rows at once is likely to cause some kind of trouble.

(2) Add to `timezones`:

```
INDEX(area_code, timezone)
```

(3) This is inefficient:

```
WHERE area_code = (SELECT LEFT(NEW.contact , 3));
```

change it to

```
WHERE area_code = LEFT(NEW.contact , 3);
```

(4) The first of these is redundant and can be dropped:

```
 KEY `FK_campaign_id_idx` (`campaign_id`),
 KEY `idx_004` (`campaign_id`,`call_status`,`test_call`),
```

(5) What is the distinction between `contact` and `contact_name`?

(6) Low-cardinality indexes (eg, `idx_active_call`) are essentially never chosen by the Optimizer, so could be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

"Standard" way - analyse indexes, table sizes and etc (Rick James already ask proper questions)

But I want suggest other way:

- disable triggers
- use ETL for prepare data

For example in talend it could look like:

- split file to many csv by 2-3M (this is for reduce memory consumption)
- in LOOP load each file - JOIN with timezones table (load once for all rows) - talend do in memory lookup and change timezones on the fly
- write final data in csv for use with LOAD INTO or use Talend MySQLBulkInsert component

Because all processes run on ETL machine in memory, it is:

- fast as much as it possible
- not lock tables during lookup

Talend is just my favourite tool, but You can choose other if search.